# Amazon Turk Command Line Tools: Invalid Configuration for Port error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, command, mechanicalturk

I am attempting to set up Amazon Turk Command Line Tools. I followed all required steps (i.e., added a system variable `JAVA_HOME` set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7`, and changed the properties file URLs to https from http). However, when I try to run any commands, I get the error below. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?  Thanks!

```
C:\aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1\bin>getbalance
An error occurred: Invalid configuration for port
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid configuration for port
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterServiceRaw.<init>(Requester
ServiceRaw.java:240)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterService.<init>(RequesterSer
vice.java:241)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.AbstractCmd.initService(AbstractCmd.java:119)

        at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.AbstractCmd.run(AbstractCmd.java:143)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.GetBalance.main(GetBalance.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration for locator
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterServiceRaw.getPort(Requeste
rServiceRaw.java:269)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterServiceRaw.<init>(Requester
ServiceRaw.java:230)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no pr
otocol: service_url=https://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/?Service=AWSMechanicalT
urkRequester
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.requester.AWSMechanicalTurkRequesterLocator.getAW
SMechanicalTurkRequesterPort(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterServiceRaw.getPort(Requeste
rServiceRaw.java:263)
        ... 5 more

C:\aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1\bin>
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar error showed up when I didn't provide `AccessKeyId` and `SecretAccessKey`. Try filling them in.